# Iterating rows with a for loop to a csv file with Pandas and Numpy Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, for-loop

The code below is meant to iterate `[Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4]` into a csv file. It saves each iteration to the csv code with the `dataframe.to_csv("sales.csv", index=False, mode='a', header=False)` code. However the code makes a separate row for each `Val` value as visualized in the `Ouput`. I want to make it so that `val1-4` are printed row by row for each iteration. How could I do that so I could get the `Expected output`. as the resultant.

```
from numpy import random
import pandas
Values = random.randint(100, size=(100000))
Number_array = random.randint(100, size=(1000))
for n in range(len(Values)):
    val1 = np.sum(Number_array) + Values[n] * len(Number_array)
    val2 = np.sum([Number_array])
    val3 = val1 * val2
    val4 = n * 2
    data =[Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4]
    dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data)
    dataframe.to_csv("input.csv", index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```

`input.csv` file:

```
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
```

Output:

```
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
49793 
48793 
-1865417447 
0
82793
48793
-255248447 
2
```

Expected output

```
Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
49793,48793, -1865417447, 0
82793, 48793, -255248447, 2
```

Comment: try `dataframe = pandas.DataFrame([data])`  instead of `dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data)` ? Just guessing looking at your code, haven't tried. Looks like you want to create 4 columns but you pass a single list instead of list of the list  which is why you end up with 1 column instead of 4.

Comment: @anky please look at time consumption at each step as you are dealing with `file-object` append which take much time then append to list and then at to file in one step

Comment: @ExplooreX Got you. :) I commented the *why is it not working part* only, may be if we are appending as a list we dont need the mode = 'a' in your answer..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Check out this code :**

```
l = []
for n in range(len(Values)):
    val1 = np.sum(Number_array) + Values[n] * len(Number_array)
    val2 = np.sum([Number_array])
    val3 = val1 * val2
    val4 = n * 2
    data =[val1, val2, val3, val4]
    # dataframe = pandas.DataFrame([data])
    l.append(data)
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(l)
dataframe.to_csv("input.csv", index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```

**Method-2**
If you want to go with @anky user comment you have to look at `len` at `len(Values)` which is about `100k` and we are dealing with `dataframe and file` at each `iteration` which take much time then appending it to `list` and then add to `file`, as here `file-process` is only `one step`

**Just change:**

```
   dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data)
```

**to:**

```
   dataframe = pandas.DataFrame([data])
```

### Time-consumption analysis

```
1st-case:
0.38395023345947266 s ± 15.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


2nd-case:  
350.7548952102661 s ± 15.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because your `dataframe` looks like that

```
>>data
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>dataframe
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

You can just `Transpose` the dataframe to get in the form you want

```
>>dataframe.T
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
```

Or you can just `nest` the data `list` to another `list` as:

```
>>dataframe = pd.DataFrame([data])
>>dataframe
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
```